# Error: "Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor" for format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have an input stream of data that contains Date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z", wherein the TimeZone needs to be preserved while propagating the Date further. 
Below is the test program (with error stack) - what is wrong in my solution ?

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-12-09 09:30:21 UTC", dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception in 1st approach: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z").toFormatter();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-12-09 09:30:21 UTC", dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception in 2nd approach: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

> Output (exception msg):
>
> Exception in 1st approach: Text '2016-12-09 09:30:21 UTC' could not be
>   parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor:
>   {HourOfAmPm=9, MinuteOfHour=30, MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=21,
>   NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0},ISO,UTC resolved to 2016-12-09 of
>   type java.time.format.Parsed
>
> Exception in 2nd approach: Text '2016-12-09 09:30:21 UTC' could not be
>   parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor:
>   {HourOfAmPm=9, MinuteOfHour=30, MicroOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=21,
>   NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0},ISO,UTC resolved to 2016-12-09 of
>   type java.time.format.Parsed

JDK version 1.8.0_111

I have read the similar questions in zoneddatetime tag but could not find a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use 
`DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");`   instead of using

```
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z");
```

So `h` in your pattern must be `H`. according to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) `h` is used when you define `clock-hour-of-am-pm`  so in addition you should have `a` as `am-pm-of-day` in your patern as well or just use `H`

Comment: instead of using hh you have to use capital HH

Comment: Got it - thanks a lot for spotting that ! Clearly java.time.* is more strict w.r.t the formats (which is good).